# Does the race of half-elves on Khorvaire in Eberron have its own name?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, races, eberron, half-elf

In Eberron, specifically on the continent of Khorvaire, the half-elves have lived on the continent for centuries, to the extent that the majority of half-elves are descended from half-elven parents, and they are effectively their own true race.

It seems peculiar to me that they would still be called "half-elves" rather than their own name.

Does their race have any canonical name other than *half-elves*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## The technical term is "Khoravar".

From the section on half-elves in the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* (p. 77-78), under the heading ["The Khoravar"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/wgte/races-of-eberron#TheKhoravar):

> When two half-elves conceive, the child is always a half-elf. Over
> the course of generations, families and communities of half-elves have
> developed their own cultural identity. Members of these families
> generally dislike the term “half-elf;” they call themselves **Khoravar**,
> an Elven term meaning “children of Khorvaire.”

The rest of the section describes the Khoravar culture.