# Does the race of half-orcs on Khorvaire in Eberron have its own name?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, races, eberron, half-orc

I recall that the half-elves of the continent of Khorvaire in the world of Eberron [have their own name](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141444/does-the-race-of-half-elves-on-khorvaire-in-eberron-have-its-own-name), the Khoravar.

Is there a similar special name for the half-orcs of the continent of Khorvaire?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike half-elves, half-orcs don’t generally live apart from their parent races so much, so it would be somewhat surprising for them to focus so strongly on the distinction. Most half-orcs are from the Shadow Marches, which is a pretty well-mixed population of human, orc, and half-orc—and considering the mixing, it’s quite likely that even those who are using the stats for orc or human still have a bit of the blood of the other in them.

At any rate, *Eberron Campaign Setting*, *Races of Eberron*, *Faiths of Eberron*, and *Wayfinder’s Guide to Eberron* all seem to lack any such name.